# Can I create simple console based Spotify app accessing only my account data?

Tags: spotify

I just wanted to use webapi to play with the metadata like playlist, artists on my own account. Is it possible to do that by REST API without using /callback to web application which receives authorization code then can get the oauth token ?

I have researched here:
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Then I found:
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow

That's it! You just need to get oauth token by giving your regular login and password credentials.